# Reading an array of numbers in parallel with Promises

Tags: javascript, algorithm, es6-promise

I have an array of numbers and I'd like to read them in parallel, with some workers (Promises), having a maximum of workers working simultaneously allowed.

I want to get the result, an array of numbers, through a Promise, when all workers have finished their work.
The order in which numbers are read is not important.

I've written some code which is close to the solution, but the workers, being promises, start their work immediately after being created, (as you can see from the "Active workers" infos printed which contains more items than maxWorkers). So I cannot control how many are actually running together, which is what I want.
What I actually want is to see a maximum of maxWorkers listed in the "Active workers" info.

A worker can create a max of maxWorkersToCreate workers, and the total workers working can be as high as maxWorkers.

This is just a toy example, the real work I have to do is to read in parallel some web resources. This is why I thought to Promises and this is why there is a setTimeout in the code (to simulate an async operation).

Library suggestions are accepted as well.

```js
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'flat', {
  value: function(depth = 1) {
    return this.reduce(function(flat, toFlatten) {
      return flat.concat((Array.isArray(toFlatten) && (depth - 1)) ? toFlatten.flat(depth - 1) : toFlatten);
    }, []);
  }
});


const workerManager = new class WorkerManager {
  constructor() {
    this.workers = [];
  }

  showWorkers() {
    let w = this.workers.filter(function(n){ return n != undefined }); 
    console.log("Active workers:", w);
  }

  setWorker(name) {
    this.workers[name] = name;
  }

  removeWorker(name) {
    delete this.workers[name];
  }
}

const MAX = 10;
var numbers = [];
for (var i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
  numbers.push(i);
}


// last position being read from workers
let maxPositionQueued = 0;
// max number of workers working 
const maxWorkers = 3;
// max workers a worker can create
const maxWorkersToCreate = 4;
// current number of workers working
let currentWorkers = 0;

function readAll(positionToRead) {
  if (currentWorkers > maxWorkers) {
    // Rescheduling worker
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        resolve(readAll(positionToRead));
      }, Math.random() * 10 + 10);
    });
  }


  function readNumber() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
      workerManager.setWorker(positionToRead);
      workerManager.showWorkers();
      console.log("Reading pos:", positionToRead);
      setTimeout(function() {
        let result = numbers[positionToRead];
        workerManager.removeWorker(positionToRead);
        resolve(result);
      }, Math.random() * 500 + 1000);
    });
  }

  currentWorkers++;
  return readNumber().then(function(response) {
    let workers = [];
    while (workers.length < maxWorkersToCreate &&
      maxPositionQueued < MAX - 1) {
      /*
       * here I'd like to queue a worker and not start it 
       * immediately
       */
      workers.push(readAll(++maxPositionQueued));
    }

    currentWorkers--;

    return Promise.all([
      response,
      workers
    ].flat()).then(function(responses) {
      return responses.flat();
    });

  }); // then reponse END

}


readAll(0).then(function(response) {
  console.log("Numbers:", response);
});
```

Comment: `but the workers, being promises, start their work immediately after being created` create a function wrapper  around the promise when called , then the promise is invoked

Comment: @Hyyan Abo Fakher: if I create functions instead of promises how can I pass them to Promise.all?

Comment: It is not necessary to use `promise.all` you can use something [like this](https://gist.github.com/anvk/5602ec398e4fdc521e2bf9940fd90f84)

Comment: Promises do not run in parallel/simultaneously, they run interleaved. JavaScript is not multi-threaded. If you want to utilize multiple cores in parallel, then you need to use WebWorkers (browser)  or fork child processes (nodejs), but that't not multi-threading but multi-processes.

Comment: @t.niese You are right, I meant "apparently in parallel"

Comment: @cdarwin you are trying to achieve what ?! multi-threading but multi-processes

Comment: @Hyyan Abo Fakher when you read remote web resources and not an array of numbers, it seems to me one can achieve parallel requests with this approach

Comment: @Hyyan Abo Fakher I read the gist you linked, however, if I'm not wrong, they show how to execute a chain promises with one promise at time. I don't understand how one can wait for multiple promises without using Promise.all

Comment: @cdarwin it is better to use web workers, anything else will just look like a hack, maybe take a look at [Parallel.js](https://parallel.js.org/)

Comment: You may check [my answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49093875/4543207) especially the comments.